# Get contained SwiftUI view from UIHostingController

Tags: swiftui

Prior to migrate to SwiftUI we created a func where we create an array of UIViews with a local var which can be first configured and extracted later:

```
var viewsArray = [UIView]()
let heights = [50.0, 100.0]

for height in heights {
    let singleView = MyView()
    singleView.setup(with customHeight: height)
    viewsArray.append(singleView)
}
```

Once array was created, we were able to cast views as? :

```
if let view = views[index] as? MyView {
    print("This view height is \(view.customHeight)")
}
```

hence, we were able to get a value casting to MyView and fetching passed value.

Now we are using SwiftUI views instead and trying to replicate the same behavior:

```
for height in heights {
   let hostingView = UIHostingController(rootView: MySwiftUIContentView(customHeight: height)).view
   views.append(hostingView)
}
```

Is there a way to cast views a in order to get contained value? I tried this approach but it fails:

```
if let view = views[index] as? MySwiftUIContentView {
   print("This view height is \(view.customHeight)")
}
```

This throws this kind of alert:

> Cast from 'UIView' to unrelated type 'MySwiftUIContentView'
> always fails

Answer (score 0):

The type of hostingView is `UIHostingController<MySwiftUIContentView>`. If you want to access the SwiftUI view it contains it is available as `rootView`.

```
if let view = views[index] as? UIHostingController {
    print("This view height is \(view.rootView.customHeight)")
}
```